# How to @Autowire services in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

Good day, guys. I have a question about autowiring services into my classes when using Springboot. All of the examples I have seen on the Internet as well as in the Springboot specification do something of the like (taking an excerpt from the Springboot version 1.5.7 specification):

```
package com.example.service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class DatabaseAccountService implements AccountService {
private final RiskAssessor riskAssessor;

@Autowired
public DatabaseAccountService(RiskAssessor riskAssessor) {
this.riskAssessor = riskAssessor;
}
// ...
}
```

This is a class that injects a property through its constructor, by means of @Autowiring the constructor. Another form is to @Autowire the property like this:

```
@Autowired
private final RiskAssessor riskAssessor
```

But, where I work, for these two methods to work, I have been told that I need to use this method:

```
 applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(Object.class)
```

They have told me that I need this in order for the @Autowired annotation to work.

Now my question to you is: why is there no simple annotation that allows the @Autowire to function correctly? (Something like @AutowiredClass). The above method is too verbose and hard to remember, so surely there must be a better way to make @Autowired work on classes in order to inject services, just like we do in Grails where we just say `def someService` and it is automatically injected.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear ... do you actually mean `applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(DatabaseAccountService.class)`? If "yes", then no, you don't need that. Just configure your "component scan" correctly.

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything special wrt application context. Make sure the RiskAssessor bean is created somewhere in Spring config.

Comment: In Spring boot, no you do not need, as long as you are in the Main class package or its subpackages

Comment: @Tom Yes, is the answer to your question

Comment: @Greg Then you don't need that line. Please check the existing answers and if they don't help you to solve the issue, then please update your question accordingly and also add a snippet of the `RiskAssessor` to show how it is annotated.

Comment: @Tom The reason I didn't check existing answers is because our software development team leader, who has a lot of experience, has taught us that that is the way you use a service in a class, and I believed him until I put some thought to it and, thinking that SpringBoot has a lot of annotations, it came as a surprise to me that such a way of autowiring services to classes is needed to inject a simple service. There is no snippet for `RiskAssessor`, it's just a bean that is injected. As I said before, I took this example from the SpringBoot Version 1.5.7 specification.

Comment: Can you please accept some answer if you believe one of them solved your problem (what it seems to be the case)? That's what is [expected from you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 7):

If you want properly use `@Autowired` in your spring-boot application, you must do next steps:

1. Add `@SpringBootApplication`to your main class
2. Add `@Service` or `@Component` annotation to class you want inject
3. Use one of two ways that you describe in question, to autowire

Comment: I think I was missing the part of adding @Component to the classes I wanted to inject the service to. Will test this when I have time and check your solution, as it provides more details.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any wiered package structure and the main class package includes all other classes you want spring to instantiate (directly or in the subpackages) a simple annotation `@ComponentScan` on your main class will help you save all those boiler plate code. Then spring will do the magic, it will go and scan the package(and subpackages) and look for classes annotated with `@Service`, `@Component` etc and instantiate it.

Even better, use `@SpringBootApplication` in your main class, this will cover `@Configuration` as well. If it is a green field project , I would encourage to start from [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io) - a template generation/scaffolding tool for spring

Comment: Do I need @Component scan in my classes I want to inject services?

Answer (score 2):

> Now my question to you is: why is there no simple annotation that allows the @Autowire to function correctly?

There is: `@SpringBootApplication`

If you put this at the root of your application (file that contains the main class) and as long as your services are at the same package or a sub-package, Spring will auto-discover, instantiate, and inject the proper classes.

There's an example in this walk-through: [REST Service with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

As described in that page:

> @SpringBootApplication is a convenience annotation that adds all of the following:
>     @Configuration tags the class as a source of bean definitions for the application context.
>     @EnableAutoConfiguration tells Spring Boot to start adding beans based on classpath settings, other beans, and various property settings.
>     @ComponentScan tells Spring to look for other components, configurations, and services in the hello package, allowing it to find the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

`@Autowired` almost works out of the box. Just do your component scanning of the class you want to *autowire* and you are done. Just make sure your main class (or main configuration class) uses `@ComponentScan("{com.example.app}")` or `@SpringBootApplication` (main class). The [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation) explain this stuff pretty good

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate the implementation of `RestService` as a `@Service` or `@Component` so *Spring* would pick it up.

```
@Service
public class MyRiskAssessorImpl implements RiskAssessor {
///
}
```

Comment: Do you mean I need to annotate my classes who are going to receive my injected services with @ Component so that @ Autowired can be used to inject a service in my class?

Comment: I mean you need to annotate the classes which are going to be `@Autowired`